# forfiles to suppress No find files not working

Tags: batch-file

I am using `forfiles` to display text files older than 300 days.
If I don't find any files `forfiles` gives an error, so I used following code to suppress the error, and return output as:

```
A:"NONE"
success
```

code below:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET res=NONE


for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('forfiles /d -300 /p E:\Webex /m *.txt /c "cmd /c echo @file ^>^>log.txt" ^| findstr error' ) do set res=%%a
ECHO A:"!res!" >>log.txt 
if "!res!" == "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." (
    ECHO B:"!res!" >>log.txt
    SET err_lv=0
) ELSE (
    SET err_lv=1
)

IF "!res!" == "NONE" SET err_lv=0

if !err_lv! equ 1 (
    ECHO failure >>log.txt
) else (
    ECHO success >>log.txt
)


pause
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Your question history shows that you seldom reply and have only marked one answer as accepted.  Please read the help section. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 4):

To eliminate the error message, add a `2>nul` to the end of the line
which redirects STDERR stream 2 (standard error) to nul.

```
forfiles /d -300 /p E:\Webex /m *.txt /c "cmd /c echo @file" 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `FORFILES /p E: /D -1 /C "cmd /c echo @path"2>nul` alone still raises the error level and caused my code to fail.

I found that in order to not trigger any try/catch or other error handling I needed to call this command from a jenkinsfile (groovy script) and what worked for me was to add a simple echo statement that would not return an error. It's cludgey but this is the simplest most effective solution for my work.

```
bat '''
            FORFILES /p E: /D -1 /C "cmd /c echo @path"2>nul
            ECHO "It's okay if we don't find any files to delete."
'''
```